# how to install @vue/cli after deprecating Request model from npm?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am working on Windows 10 and I am trying to install vue/cli using this code from its docs

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

It doesn't work and give back this error 
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated

How can I install the package?

Comment: It's a warning. So it will install. You'll get used to these kind of warnings in npm/yarn nodejs.

Comment: The CLI maintainers will update this. You can safely ignore the warning. See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5220

Comment: @user3791775 I'd recommend posting that as an answer, since it's the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mac and you encounter similar issues, include `sudo` like this: `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli` and enter your password when prompted.
That should do the trick.

Comment: I added sudo, which "worked" (vue cli will run), but wow at the deprecated and error messages! -- should I be concerned about "warn and ERR!" messages for "gyp" which occur just after the "> node install.js" message that comes out?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install vue-cli` works. But it installs Vue cli 2.x which you can upgrade using `vue upgrade`

Comment: that wont install globally vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to fix my Mac install:

1. Uninstalled vue cli first.

`sudo npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

2. Re-installed and **added a switch** to deal with some file access issue.  Which gives some warnings, but no errors.

`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm`

3. Also then, installed the dependency in the warning that printed out at the very end of the install in Step 2.

`sudo npm install -g vue@3.0.0-rc.9`

After step 3, a "vue --version" command prints "@vue/cli 4.5.4" at this point, but it would do that previously.

So for a real test, I created a new project in the vue ui, which took much longer (30+ seconds) than my original first project created after the original troubled vue cli install.

And that **new project works!** -- I clicked "serve" in the Tasks window, can see a clean build in the Output window, and the demo page loads at `http://localhost:8080/` like it supposed to! Welcome to Your Vue.js App, etc...