# I am trying to install Vuejs on my window machine but getting errors. I have attached pictures

Tags: node.js, vue.js, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOBIu.png)Ain't able to figure out what is going wrong? I have attached the inaccuracies below. I am gonna appreciate your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viLv0.png)

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue-cli@2.9.6: This package has been deprecated in favour of @vue/cli.

npm install -g @vue/cli
deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated.
```

> npm version = 6.9.0
>
> node version = 10.16.0
>
> git version = 2.25.1.windows.1

Comment: I don't see any errors

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625787/how-to-install-vue-cli-after-deprecating-request-model-from-npm

Comment: @Phil thanks for your reply. I have looked at the link you recommended me but still it is not working for me.How can i solve the deprecation warnings?

Comment: Don't worry about them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil, what i want to tell you is vue has not been recognized as internal or external command. Could you assist me?

Comment: If vue is not recognised as a command in windows have you tried looking in you environment variables to make sure its been added?